# How to generate table of contents for each section that includes all its subsections

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I can't seem to figure minitoc well enough to do this.

I have report style, and I want the main tableofcontents to show chapter and sections only. Then inside each section, I want a minitoc of contents that lists everything inside that section only, i.e. subsection, subsubsection, etc...

The same for each section.  So, I'd like something like this as the top (i.e. main) table of contents

```
1.  chapter one
1.1 section one
1.2 section two
```

The when I go to section one there will be small toc

```
section one
1.  subsection one
1.1 subsubsection one
1.2 subsubsection tow
2.  subsection two
2.1 subsubsection one
```

Whatever the numbering is, that is no problem with me. The goal is this: I want the main toc to display just chapters and sections, and the rest show in each section.

I tried this:

```
\documentclass[]{report}%
\usepackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents 
\chapter{chapter one}
\section{section one}
\minitoc
  \subsection{subsection one}
    stuff
  \subsection{subsection two}  
    stuff
\section{two}
\minitoc
  \subsection{subsection one}
    stuff
  \subsection{subsection two}  
\end{document}
```

But this shows the same toc in each sections as well as at the top. I tried also

```
\documentclass[]{report}%
\usepackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents 
\chapter{chapter one}
\section{section one}
\minitoc
  \subsection{subsection one}
    stuff
  \subsection{subsection two}  
    stuff
\section{two}
\minitoc
\mtcskip
  \subsection{subsection one}
    stuff
  \subsection{subsection two}  
\end{document}
```

same thing. ALso tried

```
\documentclass[]{report}%
\usepackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
\doparttoc
\tableofcontents 
\chapter{chapter one}
\section{section one}
\doparttoc
  \subsection{subsection one}
    stuff
  \subsection{subsection two}  
    stuff
\section{two}
\doparttoc
  \subsection{subsection one}
    stuff
  \subsection{subsection two}  
\end{document}
```

But now no toc shows up at all in each section. I am trying to follow the [minitoc.pdf](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/minitoc/minitoc.pdf) and table 1.3 there seems to be what I need to do, but I am missing something.

[image]

Any help on how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you want ToCs in sections, you would have to use `\dosecttoc`, and `\secttoc`, instead of `\doparttoc` and `\parttoc`.

However, the `minitoc` documentation says that section ToCs are not available for the `report` and `book` classes. `minitoc` will only give ToCs for the highest sectioning commands in the hierarchy of the class. So I guess, no luck here with this package.

Comment: I am little confused. You say `ToCs are not available for the report and book classes` What `tocs` are these? The screen shot I have above shows the book class. Lets start with this from the square one: Can you give any example, with any class you choose, where I can have a mini table-of-contents inside a section, where the main (top) table of contents does not display what is inside this mini table of contents? Any working example will do. The above pdf file is so complicated. It could have been replaced by few simple example one can understand.

Comment: @Nasser I said "*section* ToCs are not available for the report  and book classes". For those two classes, and similar class that have `chapters`, you can have minitocs for *chapters*. On the other hand, for the `article` class that has `section` as it highest structure, but no `chapter`, you can have minitocs in sections.